# SSRS Reports Unavailable for time frame

Tags: sql, reporting-services

can SSRS Reports be scheduled unavailable for a few hours every day mainly outside hours of operation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an HTML page called "app_offline.htm" and add your message in HTML
2. Copy this HTML file to report manager & report server directory under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services" (Please change according to your installation path)
3. Rename the file to something else to bring it online
4. You can automate this by creating two tasks in windows task scheduler which runs in predefined schedule.